# aws api error The action DescribeRegions is not valid for this web service

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i need to know different aws ec2 regions
i know aws has command line tools for this but i want to use aws api so
i generated following query request for accessing aws ec2 api

https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeRegions&AWSAccessKeyId=&Version=2013-02-01&Timestamp=2013-05-24T12%3A35%3A00Z&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&Signature=xkw62EsVWEpc3rodXADy4Q3LOquKKfHmVHrrIIGQCg0=

for which i got the following response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
* Connection #0 to host ec2.amazonaws.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
<Response>
<Errors>
 <Error>
   <Code>InvalidAction</Code>
   <Messaged >The action urn:Post is not valid for this web service.</Message>
</Error></Errors>
<RequestID>4a33917f-3403-4ebc-9a85-4b5393a031c6</RequestID>
</Response>
```

[1]   Done curl -v -get --data-urlencode DATA https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?action=DescribeRegions

[2]   Done                    AWSAccessKeyId=

[3]   Done                    Version=2013-02-01

[4]   Done                    Timestamp=2013-05-24T12%3A35%3A00Z

[5]-  Done                    SignatureVersion=2

[6]+  Done                    SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256

i signed this request query  follwing cmd bash scipt

```
 #!/bin/bash

q='GET
ec2.amazonaws.com
/
AWSAccessKeyId=<aws acces_key>&Action=DescribeRegions&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2013-05-24T12%3A35%3A00Z&Version=2013-02-01'

echo -n "$q" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "<aws secret key>" -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

output was : xkw62EsVWEpc3rodXADy4Q3LOquKKfHmVHrrIIGQCg0=
and then i gave this curl request separately away from above bash script.

```
$curl -v -get --data-encode DATA https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeRegions&AWSAccessKeyId=<aws access key>&Version=2013-02-01&Timestamp=2013-05-24T12%3A35%3A00Z&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&Signature=xkw62EsVWEpc3rodXADy4Q3LOquKKfHmVHrrIIGQCg0=
```

can any 1 tell me where i m going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the request URL. It contains characters that are being interpreted by your shell.

The clue is in the output lines like `"[1] Done ..."`. The ampersands in the URL are causing fragments of the URL to be executed as background subshells. These lines are the shell reporting that those subshells have finished.

Comment: tons of thanks for the answer and nice explanation it was qoutes " " i was missing.But again another problem now the response query says
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.I verified that my aws access key and aws secret key are fine.I mean they work perfectly for aws command line tools;so how can they cause problem here in ec2 api request query.Is my cmd bash script for signing the request query correct ? i.e echo -n "$q" | openssl dgst..

Comment: I can only guess that you haven't got the signature generation quite right. I have recently started using the new AWS CLI (http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) for this kind of thing, which does all the tedious stuff for you and is much nicer to use than the old AWS command line tools.