# How to construct signing request for Amazon EC2 API call with filters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This question is a follow-up to my [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939725/error-invalidaction-on-describeregions-api-call-amazon-aws-ec2-api) question on getting a REST API call to EC2 API working.

Having got that working, I wanted to generalize it and tried a couple of things. For example, I tried to filter by region name and make the request

```
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeRegions
&RegionName.1=us-east-1
&RegionName.2=eu-west-1
```

which they show in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeRegions.html).

Signing that was easy, stick the RegionName(s) into the signing request in their alphabetical position and sign the whole thing just as I would without them. That worked out just fine.

So I progressed to the second example that they provide in the documentation.

```
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeRegions
&Filter.1.Name=endpoint
&Filter.1.Value.1=*ap*
```

OK, I tried to put the filters into my signing parameters in the alphabetically sorted location as required ...

```
char * signing_parameters_template =
    "AWSAccessKeyId=%s&"
    "Action=DescribeRegions&"
    "Filter.1.Name=endpoint&"
    "Filter.1.Value=*ap*&"
    "SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&"
    "SignatureVersion=2&"
    "Timestamp=%s&"
    "Version=2013-08-15";
```

and sign that. I get an error that the signature doesn't match. I've tried a bunch of variations of this, no luck.

How does one sign a request that includes filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to escape the "*" in the filter

```
"Filter.1.Value=*ap*&"
```

That's it!